# Could not push my changes to my private Git-Hub. it says remote: Repository not found

Tags: git, github

I am trying to push my changes to existing Private GitHub.

Commit was successful, push fails shows below error. it works for my other colleagues.

Pull and commit works fine. only push fails.

Git extension tool: ***GitExtensions-2.48.03-SetupComplete.msi***

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe" push --progress "origin" refs/heads/MyProject:refs/heads/MyProject
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/CompanyGlobalDev/Company.git/' not found
Done
```

Comment: Is github.com/CompanyGlobalDev/Company the right url (with the right case)?

Comment: @VonC yes, it is correct. replaced my actual company name with Company. but url is correct. since it is private git I didn't specify it here.

Answer (score 0):

Github has been under DDOS attacks as of yesterday.  Could this be the problem?  Here is a link with more information.

http://arstechnica.com/security/2015/03/github-battles-largest-ddos-in-sites-history-targeted-at-anti-censorship-tools/

Comment: I tried GitExtensions24703SetupComplete version. it asks my git username, password in command prompt. then it shows same error. Repository not found

Comment: make sure you have the right permission and that you don't have only read permission on that Repository.